# Fixing one side of earphones

Tags: signal, wiring

I have a set of stereo earphones on which the left side suddenly stopped working.

[image: earphones]

After removing the plastic covers of each ear piece, I could see that none of the wires inside had disconnected.

I then did a continuity test with a digital multimeter between the solder points of the earpiece wires to each section of the 3.5mm connector.

This is what I found: [image]

Based on the above info, what is the likely cause of the left earpiece not working?

Comment: What do the red and green dots mean?  You should do resistor measurements, as the resistance of the earphones may be low enough that the continuity check on your meter can't distinguish between the earphone resistance and a short circuit.

Comment: your table shows the `R` element shorted out ... if `R` works, then you did not do the measurement correctly

Comment: @jsotola It's a matter of interpreting the results. Right works and measures below multimeter threshold for continuity. Left fails and measures above continuity threshold, so it's toast.

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies. I didn't consider the possibility of a burnt out speaker element as it's usually always the wires breaking on these cheap earphones. After reading Justme's answer I decided to change the left speaker for a spare one I had from a previous set of broken earphones. A bit of fiddly soldering and to my surprise the earphones now work perfectly again. I'll remember what you've told me about measuring resistance instead of using the continuity test mode for when the earphones break again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Burnt speaker element. Or at least there is a break in somewhere in the element, as from wire soldering points onward to TRS connector are measured to be fine.

All signals from connector go to respective speaker element. Left and ground to left speaker, right and ground to right speaker. But left speaker does not have connectivity between left signal and ground.

The only problem of the measurements is that you used the continuity test mode to determine good/bad. Unless you know what is the threshold resistance of your meter to show continuity or no continuity, and what is the speaker resistance, you may get incorrect results. Assume the threshold is 60 ohms, and right speaker is 59 ohms and left is 61 ohms. The other one shows continuity and the other one doesn't, even if there is only 2 ohms difference, and the difference is less than 4%. So do not use continuity mode unless you know how it works and what you are measuring with it.